# Using contains on a string array with ignoreCase

Tags: kotlin

I have a string array and I want to check if it contains some string while ignoring the case, so I do

```
businessCategories.contains(currentCategory, ignoreCase = true)
```

but it displays the error:

> Cannot find a parameter with this name: ignoreCase

Why doesn't my list recognise the param `ignoreCase`? I read about the function in a few places: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html and https://bladecoder.medium.com/the-kotlin-standard-function-will-not-just-improve-readability-in-this-case-but-performance-as-well-5515822ce216, so why is `ignoreCase` not available?

Comment: `businessCategories` isn't a `CharSequence`, it's an array? The documentation you've linked is for a `CharSequence`. The function you're calling is this: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains.html

Comment: @HenryTwist just realized that lol. So list doesn't have ignoreCase method? Means I need to convert `businessCategories` to CharSequence first? Or is there a better way?

Comment: No it doesn't. It checks whether the list contains a specific element. Are you looking to check whether the list contains a specific string ignoring case? If so then you want something like this: `elements.any { it.equals("Something", ignoreCase = true) }`

Comment: You can't just use any Kotlin function on an array and expect it to check the whole array, that would be very ambiguous. Also you can't 'convert' a list to a `CharSequence` without defining what that means: concatenating it? Adding commas in between? Etc.

Comment: `elements.any { it.equals("Something", ignoreCase = true) }` is what I actually need. Can you post it as the answer so that I can accept it, and maybe add a little more explanation to it that may help new Kotlin learners understand more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up your types here. The documentation you linked refers to the `contains` method on a `CharSequence`, which checks whether a string is a 'superstring' of another. What you're probably after is to check whether *any element of your array* is equal to a specific string, whilst ignoring case.

Unfortunately I don't think there is a function in the standard library to achieve this, but you can use `Array<T>.any` along with `String?.equals` to check each element, something like this:

```
val myString = "..."
stringArray.any { it.equals(myString, ignoreCase = true) }
```

You could even define a nice extension function:

```
fun Array<String>.contains(s: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean {
    
    return any { it.equals(s, ignoreCase) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in Kotlin itself, but in can be easily added using an extension function:

```
infix fun <T : CharSequence> T.inIgnoreCase(iterable: Iterable<T>): Boolean {
    return iterable.any { it.contentEquals(this, ignoreCase = true) }
}
```

It can be used this way:

```
val list = listOf("aaa", "bbb")
val string = "AAA"
string inIgnoreCase list // true
```